# Difficulty with blending two images after homography calculation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, blending

I'm working on a stitching tool using OpenCV and CUDA, currently just attempting to stitch two overlapping images.

The images are:

[image: Image 1 and Image 2 concatenated]

My process is as follows:

- Feature Detection on both images (ORB)
- Correlation Matching using brute force (Hamming)
- RANSAC estimation to produce homography matrix
- Warping second image by the homography matrix

I'm fairly happy I have these steps right, using opencv to draw a black image and then drawing the frames of the two images after this process yields the following result:

[image: Red frame shows image 1, blue frame shows image 2]

This looks about correct. What I'm having a problem with now is the blending. I want to use feather blending but the results I'm getting are entirely wrong. I've tried the following code where img1 is the cv::Mat of the first image and img2Warped is the cv::Mat of the second image after warping by the H matrix, finalImg is an empty cv::Mat.

```
auto blender = detail::Blender::createDefault(detail::Blender::FEATHER, true);

auto combinedCorners = std::vector<Point>{ image1Corners[0], image2Corners[0] };
auto combinedSizes = std::vector<cv::Size>{ image1Size, image2Size };

blender->prepare(combinedCorners, combinedSizes);

img1.convertTo(img1, CV_16SC3);
img2Warped.convertTo(img2Warped, CV_16SC3);

blender->feed(img1, Mat::ones(img1.size(), CV_8U), image1Corners[0]);
blender->feed(img2Warped, Mat::ones(img2Warped.size(), CV_8U), image2Corners[0]);

blender->blend(finalImg, Mat());
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Incorrect blend]

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong with the blending? I can't find any examples or help online using the blending technique I'm trying to use here.

Comment: i dont know whether this will solve your prblem or not, but the mask you are passing Mat::ones(img1.size(), CV_8U), should actually be warped and mask after seam finder. It is not all ones image. You need to use seam finder before blending

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `blender` expects to get unwarped images for input (that's why it requires corners as input), and you have already warped `img2`, that's why result seems off (twice more to the east and to the north).

Try feeding `img2` to the blender instead of `img2Warped`.